# What is the name of this control to see a long list in several parts? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm learning WPF (C #) and I need to do a control like the one shown in the following figure:

[image]

In this way when a list of items that is very large (I'm using a ListView), it would show it in parts and the control allows me to navigate between portions of the list.

I'm currently using two buttons (previous and next) to do the above.

My question is: Is there something I can take as an example to create what I need?

I will appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default Windows control in WPF can do what you want.

But you can create your own `UserControl` and do that. If you are not sure what is a `UserControl`, you can look at this [website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8).

**Edit on 03 / 15 / 2020**

There were already some examples of pagination `ListView` on Internet. Here are two examples:

[Paging with a ListView](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/93b90345-478f-4a06-aa73-37b112d69736/paging-with-a-listview?forum=wpf)

[WPF ListView Pagination using MVVM Pattern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64186/wpf-listview-pagination-using-mvvm-pattern) (This one put the pagination `ListView` into a `UserControl`, so it is easy to use.)

What you can do is look at their code, and get the part that you need. (In fact, you can copy and paste the codes in the links.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will investigate how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links, I'm also doing it with User Control. Also thanks for showing me the Microsoft Visual Studio forum, in Stack Over Flow it is a great sin to ask questions from beginners since they put the question in negative until you can no longer ask any more.